# Non-perfect Tense with Since

Tags: tense

Most of the time, the simple or progressive present tense is not used in the main clause, when there is a *since* clause:

> Correct: *I have been here since morning*.
>   Correct: *I have been waiting here since morning*.
>   Incorrect: **I am here since morning*.
>   Incorrect: **I am waiting here since morning*.

But sometimes the non-perfect tense seems alright, as in:

> 1: *Last night you were so pale, but You **are looking** so much better since morning*.
>   2: *Last night you were so pale, but You **have been looking** so much better since morning*.

I think the first sentence indicates that the situation is changing (the person's getting better and better).

And sometimes the non-perfect tense sounds even more eligible, as in:

> *You **are** the first student to get an A from that teacher since 2010.*
>   <sup>?</sup> *You **have been** the first student to get an A from that teacher since 2010.*

So, when exactly can/should we use a non-perfect tense with *since*?

Answer (score 1):

There's two different but closely related meanings here. The first is that something has been happening over a period of time, and the other is that something hasn't been happening over a period of time, but is happening now. The first uses perfect, the second uses present.

Edit: Also, be careful of what is being said. "You *are* the valedictorian of the Class of 2016." That's something that will continue to be true until 2060, or so. When the guy dies, then it's only true that he *was* the valedictorian. In the meantime, you could use either. The present man *is* the valedictorian of that class, and him as the new graduate *was* the valedictorian then, too.